# How to change font on Textmate 2 file browser?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

How can I config Textmate 2 File Browser window to use the (smaller) font in Textmate 1.5?

[image]   　 [image]

Comment: No luck: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/issues/237

Comment: This is an ancient question, but has the answer changed in the 6 years since? I actually want to increase the sidebar font-size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not currently possible. I did try and find a reference in the mailing list archives, but couldn't so may have seen this on IRC.